Failed to run Github action after pushing more commits into current PR
Hi I have the following github action. Its aim is to automatically create and update PRs.
Let's say I have a book with multiple languages. First, I create a new branch with the name pattern like "handbook_v1.1_en" to implement changes in English version. After that, the Github Action will help me to automatically create 7 other branches and PRs according to language versions, so my colleague can come and implement changes in language versions. This step worked
However, after create a PR for en version, if I push more commits into it, the following error occur:

Could anyone help me to revise the code. In addition, if possible, is there a way to notify other github users about anytime a PR is created or updated. For example, user A will be notified for French PR, user B and C will be notified for Spanish PR

    name: Create Translation Branches and PRs
    
    on:
      pull_request:
        types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]
    
    
    jobs:
      create_translation_branches:
        if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'handbook_v') && endsWith(github.head_ref, '_en') 
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout repository
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
          - name: Set up Git
            run: |
              git config --global user.name 'ntluong95'
              git config --global user.email 'ph.ntluong95@gmail.com'
    
          - name: Install GitHub CLI
            run: |
              sudo apt update
              sudo apt install -y gh
    
    
          - name: Create language branches and PRs
            run: |
              LANGS=("fr" "es" "vn" "jp" "tr" "pt" "ru")  
              PR_BRANCH="${{ github.head_ref }}"  
              VERSION_SUFFIX="${PR_BRANCH#handbook_}"
              BASE_BRANCH="main"
    
              for lang in "${LANGS[@]}"; do
                NEW_BRANCH="handbook_${VERSION_SUFFIX/_en/_$lang}"
                # Check if the branch already exists
                if ! git rev-parse --verify --quiet "${NEW_BRANCH}"; then
                  git checkout -b "${NEW_BRANCH}"
                else
                  git checkout "${NEW_BRANCH}" 
                  git pull "${PR_BRANCH}" "${NEW_BRANCH}" --rebase
                fi
    
                git push origin "${NEW_BRANCH}"
                gh pr create --base $BASE_BRANCH --head $NEW_BRANCH --title "Handbook ${VERSION_SUFFIX/_en/} $lang" --body "Automated pull request for $lang handbook version ${VERSION_SUFFIX/_en/}"
              done
            env:
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}




If you want to solve, fetch first (and then merge).
git fetch origin "${NEW_BRANCH}"
git push origin "${NEW_BRANCH}"

If you want to hack, use the --force option.
git push --force origin '${NEW_BRANCH}'



I tried but it did not work. Here is the error:
Switched to a new branch 'handbook_v1.1_fr'

branch            handbook_v1.1_fr -> FETCH_HEAD
[new branch]      handbook_v1.1_fr -> origin/handbook_v1.1_fr
To https://github.com/appliedepi/epirhandbook_quarto
! [rejected]        handbook_v1.1_fr -> handbook_v1.1_fr (non-fast-forward)

Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
its remote counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes,
use 'git pull' before pushing again.
